# Persistent random steps decorations during beamer \uncover

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, decorations, pgfmath

I'm using a random steps decoration with a path that appears through several uncover transitions.  Currently the decoration is redrawn in each instance of the slide.  How can I change this behavior.  A minimal example follows.  Thanks.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}  
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\uncover<1-3>{  
\fill [decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=2pt}] (0,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 0.4cm);  
}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}  
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this should be more mentioned in tutorials since it's really necessary whenever you have to deal with randomly generated graphics. It's often the case that you need to repeat a drawing multiple times with slight differences and there's no simple way to generate the data and store it, all from latex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the random seed each time you draw the ellipse, like so:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\uncover<1-3>{
\pgfmathsetseed{1234} % Choose a four-digit number here
\fill [decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=2pt}] (0,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 0.4cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The best part is that `\pgfmathsetseed` is local so outside this tikzpicture environment the pseudo-random number generator will behave as usual.

And by the way [random.org](http://www.random.org/) is a cool place to get random numbers to use as seeds.  [Here's](http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1000&max=9999&col=5&base=10&format=html&rnd=new) one just for you.

Comment: Was looking for this for a time... thanks, too!